# JMeter + WebDriver Sampler how to save token from auhtorization cookie

Tags: authentication, selenium, cookies, webdriver, jmeter

I've got a test plan in JMeter that is testing my API. To have it working correctly, I used HTTP Cokkie Manager where I used to define manually 2 variables called JAuth and Juath1 where I was typing manually generated token , I just copy it from my real browser.

I would like to have it more automated, so I have decided to use WebDriver Sampler to log into my service and obtain this 2 cookies/tokens.

I have simple question, how to get access to cookie element ?

This is my test plan at this moment 
[Test Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0ZEU.png)
[WebDriver code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55NTy.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
var cookies = WDS.browser.manage().getCookies()
// or 
var cookie = WDS.browser.manage.getCookieNamed('your_cookie_name')
var ctx = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext()
var vars = ctx.getVariables()
vars.put("cookies", cookies)
```

should help you to get the cookies from the browser and store them into `${cookies}` JMeter Variable so you will be able to do what you need with them.

See the following links for reference:

- [WebDriver.Options.getCookies()](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html#getCookies--)
- [WebDriver.Options.getCookieNamed()](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html#getCookieNamed-java.lang.String-)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)